# Nodejs construct the public key using public key string

Tags: node.js, cryptography, jose

I have a public key string as follows
let pk_str = "public key strig here" and I am using the library `jose` to verify a JWS

```
            (async() => {
                const decoder = new TextDecoder();
                const jws = vc_proof_value;
                const { payload, protectedHeader } = await compactVerify(jws, pk_str);
    
                console.log(protectedHeader)
                console.log(decoder.decode(payload))
              })();
```

I am getting the following error when trying to run the script

```sh
(node:75986) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Key must be one of type KeyObject, CryptoKey, or Uint8Array. Received type string
```

Is there a way to construct the key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NodeJS (I refer to NodeJS, since you have tagged this), the public key is passed as `KeyObject` wich is created with [`crypto.createPublicKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createpublickey_key). You didn't say much about the key, presumably it's PEM encoded (since it's a string). In this case, you simply have to pass the PEM encoded key:

```js
var key = crypto.createPublicKey(pk_str);
```

If in the `compactVerify()` call `pk_str` is replaced by `key`, verification works.

In addition to PEM keys (default), JWK and DER keys (X.509/SPKI or PKCS#1) are also supported.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/types/types.KeyLike.md#readme) is the documentation for the `key` argument of all applicable functions.